# Modifying the Portable Extensible Metadata project

Tags: .net, entity-framework, edmx

I would like to modify the [Portable Extensible Metadata project](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2010/01/13/introducing-the-portable-extensible-metadata.aspx), but there is no source code. I do have the [extension starter kit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DesignerExtStartKit/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Home&version=3) but the PEM project does a lot more than the extension kit.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you want to do from your question, so [read this and see if it helps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsimmons/entityroots-an-ef-extensibility-exercise).

Comment: I am trying to add a property whose value needs to be selected from a list of items in a dropdown